# in ASP.Net, how can I require contact details before allowing a download

Tags: asp.net, download, contact-form

I want to let site visitors download our company collateral, and would like to collect some contact details.  I want the process to be as low friction as possible, but i do want every visitor to go through the process of being asked for their details, so I don't want the download page to be available directly.  I am not requiring a log-in, obviously.

Ideas?

Comment: Can't you just store a flag in the session to indicate the user filled out the form, and check that flag before serving the download file?

Comment: I ended up using the session flag idea - easiest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can you should use a Session cookie to store if they have already given you their details or not, if they have just allow the download, if not then show them the details page.

The problem with Sessions though is that not all computers support cookies, and some countries (UK) are putting in place tougher cookie policies so you need to ask for the users permission before you allow them to be put on the computer.

Tracking by IP Address + User-agent is also tricky since they can be duplicated by some ISPs forcing people through proxies, or fail in large companies.

I think you should either go with the Session approach and accept its not perfect, or have a login system.

Comment: ASP.NET forms auth uses cookies by default, but you can go cookieless.